# Custom dropdown select with css and html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a custom drop-down menu with html and css only.
I'm wondering if is possible to work with focus instead of hover? now is on hover and works but I want to expand that select onclick.

Here I have a fiddle example: **http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1084/**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use hover on the `li`, use hover on the `a`:

```
a:hover + ul, a:focus + ul, a:active + ul {}
```

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/1728264)

Comment: Why does not work if I put a link on that <a></a>? fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1091/

Comment: Works like this http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/RwtHn/1098/ Like I've said in my answer, don't use `:hover` and especially `:focus` on `li`, use it on the link. And have `tabindex='1'` on the link as well.

Comment: hmmmm this is so weird, it works on chrome and IE8 but does not worknig on firefox ...

Comment: have you tried to click on that links ? is not redirecting to google page how is mentioned in <a "href".

Comment: Oh, you mean the ones in the submenu? The way you've written it, it's a relative url. Use it with http:// in front of it. This *won't redirect in jsFiddle iframe* either (from the jsFiddle iframe you can open it in a new tab if you add `target='_blank'` http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/RwtHn/1101/), but it will work in your project.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1087/
Wow. I'm surprised this is even possible with just HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Abraham Why does not work if I put a link on that <a></a>?                       fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1091/

Comment: What's wrong? It works when I click on the links (jsFiddle stops the page from loading, though)